# Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method error... though it implements method

Tags: java, class, interface, overriding

I'm getting this error message which should not be showing.
First of all after creating interface I copied its method into all classes that implements this interface - but the error is still showing.

this currently looks like this:

```
interface Shape {
    String getShapeName();

    double getField();
}

class Circle implements Shape {
    String name;
    double r;

    public Circle(String name, double r) {
        this.name = name;
        this.r = r;
    }

    @Override
    public double getField(double r) {
        return Math.PI * Math.pow(r, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public String getShapeName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class Square implements Shape {
    String name;
    double a;

    public Square(String name, double a) {
        this.name = name;
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public double getField(double a) {
        return Math.pow(a, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public String getShapeName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class Triangle implements Shape {
    String name;
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;

    public Triangle(String name, double a, double b, double c) {
        this.name = name;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public double getField(double a, double b, double c) {
        double p = (a + b + c) / 2;
        return Math.sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c));
    }

    @Override
    public String getShapeName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

And I have no idea why... I saw that this question was asked a few times but in most cases it was a result of not implementing some methods from interface (or a wrong typing method name which are not my cases as the interface methods were copied to all 3 classes...

Comment: `double getField();` and `double getField(double r);` are not the same.

Comment: Shape is not imported but created (and YES - the problem given REQUIRED to create your own Shape interface). And why are they not the same - does adding constructor (extending implemented method) ruins it?

Comment: No, a method has a *signature*, which identifies a method. The signature is the name plus a list of the parameter types. If a method has the same name, but different parameter types, it is considered to be a different method. A method with the same name but different parameter typed is said to be an *overload*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```java
interface Shape {
    String getShapeName();
    double getField();
}
```

however, you *explicitly state* in your sub-classes, that you override:

```java
@Override
public double getField(double r) {...}
```

`double getField()` and `double getField(double r)` are not the same.

[Overriding and Hiding Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html#:%7E:text=The%20ability%20of%20a%20subclass,the%20method%20that%20it%20overrides.):

> An instance method in a subclass with the same signature (name, plus the number and the type of its parameters) and return type as an instance method in the superclass overrides the superclass's method.

Side-note: [`@Override`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Override.html) (which is `@Retention(SOURCE)`) annotation on top of your method, *enforces* you to *override* corresponding method, otherwise you will not be able to compile your file.